# Polynomial excel axis scale

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to have my x axis in Excel be of polynomial scale. In other words:

Default axis scaling: Tick marks units are 'n'
Logarithmic axis scaling: Tick marks units are 'b^n' where b is a base
What I would want: Tick mark units are 'n^2'

Although I am not very confident this is possible in Excel's default, are there obvious ways to VBA this up?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you just wanting to control which spots get tick mark labels, with the spacing still linear?  If not, I don't understand what your spacing would look like.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So instead of equally spaced tick marks that go: 0 1 2 3 for default linear scaling and instead of 0 10 100 1000 for the logarithmic scaling option, mine would go 0 1 4 9 (the squares of n). For all of these, the spacing between ticks would be constant.

Answer (score 0):

Are you are talking about scaling your axis like this?

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using an X-Y scatter plot, by the way (for which one cannot edit the horizontal axis labels, as you have done in your line chart). But either way, it looks like you are suggesting just changing the labels of the tick marks, rather than the scale of the axis. The difference is that in addition to the obvious change of labels, a change of scale would also change the way the data is represented. This option is currently available natively with log (Format Axis->Logarithmic scale). I was wondering if there was an easy way to do it with powers.

Comment: I misinterpreted the part of the comment that you made to Adam where you said "the spacing between ticks would be constant." I am going to delete the answer so that it will not be confusing to others who may look this thread up in the future. Hope you have good luck with finding a solution.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: No, unfortunately it is not. What I am looking for is the same behavior as excel's "Logarithmic Scale" (where the pixel spacing between ticks really *is* constant) except for the fact that instead of a factor of 10^n between ticks, it would be n^2. I recommend you try turning on the logarithmic scale option in excel to see how it behaves. It doesn't just affect the labels of the x axis, it fundamentally changes the way the data is presented in the chart area itself (a linear x-y relationship would *not* be a line on the chart with logarithmic scale on). Thank you for your help, though.